# Convert a gson.JsonObject to JSONObject

Tags: java, gson

I have a `gson.JsonObject` object. What is the easiest way to create a `org.json.JSONObject` object from it?

Comment: TBH having two different JSON Parsers in a single project sounds like an hassle and you should check if you can't provide all components of your project with a single parser library, rather than switching back and forth between the two APIs.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

get JSON string again from `JsonObject` and parse it in `JSONObject`

```
JsonObject gson = new JsonParser().parse("{\"id\":\"value\"}").getAsJsonObject();

JSONObject jo2 = new JSONObject(gson.toString());
```

Answer (score 7):

```
new org.json.JSONObject(gson.toJson(gson.JsonObject));
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider **json** below as a **JSONObject**.

JsonObject gson = JsonParser.parseString( **json**.toString() ),getAsJsonObject();