# Convert Java object to JsonObject

Tags: java, json, android-volley

I retrieve an Inventory object by making an HTTP GET using Volley:

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
        Constants.API_URL + "inventory/lastInventoryWithLines/" + MyContext.User.getSiteId().toString(), null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    inventory[0] = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), Inventory.class);
                    ...
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("InventoryActivity", e.getMessage());
                }
                finally {
                    showProgress(false);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   ...
               }
           }
);
queue.add(req);
```

The important line is:

```
gson.fromJson(response.toString(), Inventory.class);
```

I've decorated my Inventory class with @SerializedName:

```
public class Inventory {
    @SerializedName("InventoryId")
    private UUID InventoryId;

    @SerializedName("Title")
    private String Title;
    ...
}
```

so this deserialization is easy.

Now, I want to update this Inventory object, and send it back to the server.
Volley needs a JSONObject. So my question is: how could I convert my Inventory object to a JSONObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you have to do:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.toJsonTree(myUpdatedInventory, Inventory.class).getAsJsonObject();
```

I didn't notice you weren't solely using google gson, so here is the updated answer, taken from another [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976443/convert-a-gson-jsonobject-to-jsonobject) question:

```
new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(inventory[0], Inventory.class));
```

Comment: that gives me a compiler error: "error: incompatible types: JsonObject cannot be converted to JSONObject"
As the JsonObjectRequest needs a org.json.JSONObject, but getAsJsonObject returns a com.google.gson.JsonObject...